# Images don't work on server Play Framework

Tags: html, playframework, routes

I'm having a problem with images in Play.

This is the way I access the image

```
src="@routes.Assets.at("/images/logo-mobile-control-white.png/")"
```

It works when I access from local (`localhost:9000`), but when I access from another computer (`http://10.253.3.243:9000`) the images don't work.

Here is the code from the local

> img src="/assets//images/logo-mobile-control-white.png/" width="180" height="60" border="0" title="Mobile
>                 Control" alt="Logo Mobile
>                 Control"

And Here is the code from the server

> img src="/assets//images/logo-mobile-control-white.png/" width="180" height="60" border="0" title="Mobile Control" alt="Logo Mobile Control"

Just the same

Help me please!

Comment: Use the browsers inspector - and compare html code in both case... we can't guess what's wrong o.O

Comment: do you use `base` tag in your html?

Comment: Remove the leading and trailing slash from the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use this

```
src="@routes.Assets.at("images/logo-mobile-control-white.png")"
```

---

This will produce the following result:

```
<image src="/assets/images/logo-mobile-control-white.png"/>
```

Comment: Correct if route for assets is defined by default like `GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)` but I defined my routes as `GET  /images/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file)` so in that case you need to access it as `src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/images" , logo-mobile-control-white.png")"`